# Unable to import freegames python package : AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Sequence'

Tags: python, pip, attributeerror, python-3.10

Python version : 3.10

I was trying to install the [freegames](https://pypi.org/project/freegames/) python package using the following pip command

```
C:\Users\praty>pip install freegames
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting freegames
  Downloading freegames-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (108 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 108 kB 504 kB/s
Installing collected packages: freegames
Successfully installed freegames-2.3.2
```

But while importing the same on my python environment I was getting this error

```
C:\Users\praty>python
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import freegames
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\praty\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\freegames\_init_.py", line 61, in <module>
    from .utils import floor, line, path, square, vector
  File "C:\Users\praty\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\freegames\utils.py", line 77, in <module>
    class vector(collections.Sequence):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Sequence'
```

How do I resolve the same?

Comment: Do you happen to have a file named collections? (Which overrides the built-in one)

Comment: in my working directory? no

Comment: Version 2.4.0 was released today and supports Python 3.10. Refer to the "Free Python Games Issue Tracker" in the docs at http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/freegames/#references to file bugs in the future.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For quite some time `Sequence` was importable from `collections`:

```
$ python2.7 -c "from collections import Sequence"
$ python3.4 -c "from collections import Sequence"
$ python3.5 -c "from collections import Sequence"
$ python3.6 -c "from collections import Sequence"
```

Starting from Python 3.7 there was a warning the class has been moved to `collections.abc`:

```
$ python3.7 -c "from collections import Sequence"
-c:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3,and in 3.9 it will stop working
$ python3.8 -c "from collections import Sequence"
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
$ python3.9 -c "from collections import Sequence"
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
```

In Python 3.10 this became an error:

```
$ python3.10 -c "from collections import Sequence"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/home/phd/.local/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
$ python3.10 -c "from collections.abc import Sequence"
```

Report the problem to the author of `freegames`. Downgrade to Python 3.9. Learn that you should never be so fast to upgrade to the latest and greatest versions.

Answer (score 1):

This way can solved my issue.

import collections

collections.Mapping = collections.abc.Mapping

collections.Sequence = collections.abc.Sequence

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been resolved

import collections.abc as collections

[module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping', issue on MACOS for SDK installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195545/module-collections-has-no-attribute-mapping-issue-on-macos-for-sdk-installa)