# AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute

Tags: python, pycharm

ide Pycharm. Google SDK installed lastest. What the problem? i used Python Interpreter 3.10 lastest. frozendict installed lastest, uplink installed, mapping installed

```
File "C:\Users\vgorbunov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\allure\pytest_plugin.py", line 9, in <module>
from allure.common import AllureImpl, StepContext
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
File "C:\Users\vgorbunov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 168, in exec_module
exec(co, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\vgorbunov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\allure\common.py", line 19, in <module>
from allure.structure import Attach, TestStep, TestCase, TestSuite, Failure, Environment, EnvParameter
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
File "C:\Users\vgorbunov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 168, in exec_module
exec(co, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\vgorbunov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\allure\structure.py", line 14, in <module>
class Attach(xmlfied('attachment',
File "C:\Users\vgorbunov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\allure\rules.py", line 116, in xmlfied
class MyImpl(namedlist('XMLFied', [(item[0], None) for item in items])):
File "C:\Users\vgorbunov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\namedlist.py", line 398, in namedlist
fields, defaults = _fields_and_defaults(typename, field_names, default, rename)
File "C:\Users\vgorbunov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\namedlist.py", line 252, in _fields_and_defaults
if isinstance(field_names, _collections.Collection):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'
```

Comment: Vladislav, hi.
Probably it's duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195545/module-collections-has-no-attribute-mapping-issue-on-macos-for-sdk-installa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping', issue on MACOS for SDK installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195545/module-collections-has-no-attribute-mapping-issue-on-macos-for-sdk-installa)