# How to fix "AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'" with experta package?

Tags: python, experta

I'm trying to use the experta library. I installed the library but when I try and run my program, I get an error on this line:

```
import experta
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jodne\PycharmProjects\CPCS331ESproject\TrialNerror.py", line 3, in <module>
    import experta
  File "C:\Users\jodne\PycharmProjects\CPCS331ESproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\experta\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .engine import KnowledgeEngine
  File "C:\Users\jodne\PycharmProjects\CPCS331ESproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\experta\engine.py", line 13, in <module>
    from experta.fact import InitialFact
  File "C:\Users\jodne\PycharmProjects\CPCS331ESproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\experta\fact.py", line 9, in <module>
    from experta.utils import freeze, unfreeze
  File "C:\Users\jodne\PycharmProjects\CPCS331ESproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\experta\utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    from frozendict import frozendict
  File "C:\Users\jodne\PycharmProjects\CPCS331ESproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\frozendict\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    class frozendict(collections.Mapping):
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'
```

[image: Pycharm Python Interpreter settings highlighting experta package]

What am I missing?

Comment: `collections.Mapping` was moved in Python 3.10.  Can you upgrade to a newer version of the `frozendict` module that knows about this change?

Comment: Or check what is the supported Python versions of the experta package. It seems that package hasn't yet adapted to the changes in `collections.Mapping` starting from Python 3.10. You might need to downgrade to a lower version of Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping', issue on MACOS for SDK installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195545/module-collections-has-no-attribute-mapping-issue-on-macos-for-sdk-installa)

Answer (score 0):

Installing experta in a virtual env where I downloaded python 3.8 was the solution that fixed it for me.

Note : 3.9 didn't work, it gave me the same errror