# Problem with R kernel under SoS Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

`R kernel` is not working under `SoS Notebook` (under a regular notebook there is no error).

The following error appear for any command:

```
cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

and the console shows the warning:

```
WARNING: Failed to locate subkernel R with kernel "ir" and language "R": cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

[image: Error using R kernel in SoS]

Here some details of my installation:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  bash       /home/leoca/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/bash
  ir         /home/leoca/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  octave     /home/leoca/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/octave
  python3    /home/leoca/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  sos        /home/leoca/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/sos

$ pip list | grep sos
sos                               0.23.4
sos-bash                          0.20.0
sos-notebook                      0.23.4
sos-r                             0.19.6
```

Comment: This seems to be a python version issue. With 3.6, I can do `from collections import Sequence`. With 3.10, I get an `ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections`.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69598162/1878788

Comment: Someone proposed a bug fix: https://github.com/vatlab/sos-r/pull/29/commits/242e0b2a3faa3782a6c1caafa098ef9280845390

However, it is not integrated in the main code yet, so meanwhile, you can edit your `lib/python3.10/site-packages/sos_r/kernel.py` file manually.